# PHP en esta variable $sql me da errores de sintaxis

Tags: php, php7

Tengo esta sentencia :

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre,apellidos,usuario,email,password) 
    VALUES ('$datos['nombre']', '$datos['apellidos']', '$datos['usuario']', '$datos['email']', '$datos['password']')";
```

Esta variable la tengo en la siguiente **funcion**:

```
public function insertar($datos){

    $conexion = $this->c->conectar();

    // $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre,apellidos,usuario,email,password) 
    //      VALUES('$datos['nombre']','$datos['apellidos']','$datos['usuario']','$datos['email']','$datos['password']')";

    $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre,apellidos,usuario,email,password) 
    VALUES ('$datos['nombre']', '$datos['apellidos']', '$datos['usuario']', '$datos['email']', '$datos['password']')";

    // return $result = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
    return $result = $conexion->query($sql);

}
```

Me suelta el siguiente error : `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''`. 
Pero tengo que poner las comillas si no no puedo usar mi **array asociativo** de `$datos`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que hay una ambigüedad de comillas dentro del string que forma el query y en este caso PHP no puede evaluar los valores del array.
Puedes resolverlo así:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre,apellidos,usuario,email,password) 
    VALUES ('".$datos['nombre']."', '".$datos['apellidos']."', '".$datos['usuario']."', '".$datos['email']."', '".$datos['password']."')";
```

O también

```
$nombre = $datos['nombre'];
$apellidos = $datos['apellidos'];
$usuario = $datos['usuario'];
$email = $datos['email'];
$password = $datos['password'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre,apellidos,usuario,email,password) 
    VALUES ('$nombre', '$apellidos', '$usuario', '$email', '$password')";
```

Answer (score 1):

Saludos puedes realizar lo siguiente:

```
public function insertar($datos){

    $conexion = $this->c->conectar();

    $nombre = $datos['nombre'];
    $apellidos = $datos['apellidos'];
    $usuario = $datos['usuario'];
    $email = $datos['email'];
    $password = $datos['password'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre,apellidos,usuario,email,password) 
    VALUES ('$nombre', '$apellidos', '$usuario', '$email', '$password')";

    return $result = $conexion->query($sql);

}
```

Si te fijas asigno en variables el cotenido de **$datos**, espero te sirva..!!

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un problema con las comillas con la cadena que asignas a la variable `$sql`, las comillas sencillas de los nombres de variables (`$datos['apellidos']`), rompen la cadena con las comillas de los valores de la consulta (`'{$datos['apellidos']}'`).

Una forma para evitar eso es incluyendo las variables de esta forma:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre,apellidos,usuario,email,password) VALUES ('{$datos['nombre']}', '{$datos['apellidos']}', '{$datos['usuario']}', '{$datos['email']}', '{$datos['password']}')";
```